# Should I use exceptions for notifying the user about bad input?

Tags: exception

I have a webtool where users can send emails to that are being parsed. When the parsing fails, because of bad input I want to send an error message back to the user. I would like to throw exceptions for parsing errors in the several parsing methods, catch them and send the errormail back to the user if an axception appears.

But I remember, that exceptions should not be used for errors like that, but only for situations that could not be predicted. So, should I use exceptions here or should I not?

Answer (score 0):

Usually exception is only expensive when it's thrown.

If bad input is rare it doesn't hurt. But if it's frequent then performance will be notably affected.